# How to write data to the ActiveMemory Server used in the XCF system?

Tags: xcf, active-memory

If you are using [XCF](https://code.ai.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/trac/xcf) you can write all your data into an Active Memory Server. Other processes can now access all this data. Taking the first steps with XCF, my question now is what steps have to be done to get some example data in the active memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a short answer to this question to give some pointers for the active memory stuff:

First you have to create a working xcf Environment. This is mainly [configuring](http://xcf.sourceforge.net/docs/xcf/configfiles.html) your dispatcher. 
Then you have to run an active memory server. You can use the command line tool [xcfinfo](http://xcf.sourceforge.net/docs/xcf/tools.html#Interactive+Introspection) to look if your active memory server is active in your xcf environment. 
If your memory server is running you can do some initial testing with the [java memory interface](https://code.ai.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/trac/xcf/wiki/JavaMemoryInterface) tool to see how and if your server is working. For inserting and listenging to the memory have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~eriedenk/blog/2009/02/howto-xcf-activememory.html).