# Is it possible to access an xcf active memory server with python?

Tags: python, xcf, active-memory

I'm playing around with the [XCF](https://code.ai.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/trac/xcf) active memory server. Is there a python library to access the contents of the active memory server?

#### Related:

[How to write data to the ActiveMemory Server used in the XCF system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901568/how-to-write-data-to-the-activememory-server-used-in-the-xcf-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to one of the developers there is an outdated version of a python API for publish and subscribe over XCF. This API is not capable of contacting an active memory server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [their documentation](http://xcf.sourceforge.net/docs/am/index.html), the answer appears to be "yes".

Comment: The documentation only says that there is a XCF API not that the API is fully capable of using all of the active memory interfaces